# Laravel generate urls with parameters

Tags: url, laravel

I want to generate url with parameters in Laravel like this:

```
http://example.com/validate_email?user_id=31&confirmation_code=ihlasfsafe
```

I tried

```
URL::to('validate_email', array('user_id' => $user_id, 'confirmation_code' => $confirmation_code));
```

But it gives me:

```
http://example.com/validate_email/31/ihlasfsafe
```

So how can I do it correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use:

```
URL::to('validate_email').'?'.http_build_query(array('user_id' => $user_id, 'confirmation_code' => $confirmation_code));
```

to achieve this

Comment: Seems like you answered lots of my quenstions, saved me quite some time, sincerely thank you!